# CNN architecture predicts always the same class

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using this CNN architecture :

```
def createModel():


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(96, (11, 11), strides=(4,4), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(224,224,3))) #, input_shape=input_shape
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))


model.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))


model.add(Conv2D(384, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(384, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu'))



model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

return model
```

At the total, it makes 226,065,795 trainable parameters... I train my model on a quite small dataset. Indeed, I have three classes, each one contains 1000 images, that are split between training and validation set. I used OneHotEncoding.

However, when I train the model, the overall accuracy tends to a very low result : 32%. I am using `categorical_crossentropy` loss function. When looking deeper, it seems that the model always predicts `1,0,0` vector, i.e. the first class and never the others, even for the trained data that thus have been shown to the model.

What's the problem there ? Why do I have poor results ? My dataset is balanced tough. Is it because my number of parameters is too high compared to the amount of data? I don't understand...

EDIT : removing Dropout still keeps the bad thing

Comment: Where is the training part? Did you train over several epoches?

Comment: @Gizmo I trained for several epochs and used EarlyStopping but the accuracy rapidly converges to 32% and does not improve. I have shuffled my data, also

Comment: But why does it stop at such an accuracy? It seems like there is something wrong.

Comment: @Indeed and that's why I asked the question :). No enough data w.r.t to the network complexity ?

Comment: Depends on the data, but I think you should be fine there. It just seems like the network isn't trained at all. 32% for three classes is exactly the result an untrained network would give. Maybe your cost function is wrong.

Comment: @Gizmo I used categorical entropy with one hot encoding...

Comment: @MysteryGuy Have you normalized your images? What learning rate and optimizer do you use?

Comment: @today I normalised my data, used both `rmsprop` and `adam` optimizers (without any difference tough). I tested with a smaller number of data but it still keeps to predict only once class. Maybe dropout is too high ??

Comment: @MysteryGuy Well, I would do these to resolve the issue: 1) make sure the labels are one-hot encoded correctly, 2) make sure images are properly normalized (e.g. in range [0,1]), 3) make sure activation of last layer is `softmax` and the loss function used is `categorical_crossentropy`, 4) remove the dropout layers to see if it overfits on training data (it should, considering the size of network), 5) use a smaller learning rate (i.e. `optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5)`), 6) use a smaller filter size for the first layer(s) (e.g. `(3,3)`) since they are used for extracting local low-level features.

Comment: @MysteryGuy Which is the split proportion of your validation and train sets?

Comment: @H. Tacon it's 70-30

Comment: @today it seems like a network architecture... When I remove some conv layers, it goes right